# Fix or not more vulerabilities in my new expo app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, native

I'm created a simple expo app for iOS and Android. I'm trying to configure realtime database and after add the dependencies, i do: npx expo install. So i have 9 vulnerabilities (6 moderate, 3 high), maybe for some old oversion:

```
        #npm audit report
        
            lodash.trim  *
            Severity: moderate
            Regular Expression Denial of Service (ReDoS) in lodash - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-29mw-wpgm-hmr9
            No fix available
            node_modules/lodash.trim
              montage  >=0.14.12
              Depends on vulnerable versions of lodash.trim
              Depends on vulnerable versions of q-io
              node_modules/montage
    
            qs  <=6.2.3
            Severity: high
            Prototype Pollution Protection Bypass in qs - 
    https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-gqgv-6jq5-jjj9
    qs vulnerable to Prototype Pollution - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-hrpp-h998-j3pp
    fix available via `npm audit fix`
    node_modules/q-io/node_modules/qs
            q-io  >=1.3.0
            Depends on vulnerable versions of qs
            node_modules/q-io

           semver  7.0.0 - 7.5.1
Severity: moderate
semver vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-c2qf-rxjj-qqgw
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install expo@49.0.23, which is a breaking change
node_modules/@expo/image-utils/node_modules/semver
  @expo/image-utils  <=0.0.1-canary-20240109-93608d8 || >=0.3.10-alpha.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of semver
  node_modules/@expo/image-utils
    @expo/cli  <=0.0.0-canary-20231123-1b19f96-4 || >=0.0.1-canary-20231125-d600e44
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/image-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/prebuild-config
    node_modules/@expo/cli
      expo  50.0.0-alpha.0 - 50.0.14
      Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/cli
    @expo/prebuild-config  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/image-utils
    node_modules/@expo/prebuild-config
```

I have the last version of expo and node. Are these vulnerabilities that could cause problems in my app?

I hope I can continue creating my app